# How to create conditional interfaces without writing base classes in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Not sure what this is called, but let's say I got these interfaces

```js
interface Dog {
    type: "dog"
    canBark: boolean
}

interface Cat {
    type: "cat"
    canMeow: boolean
}
```

I would like to be able to say: If `type="Dog"`, there should be a `canBark` property (as a boolean) and no other properties. If `type="Cat"`, there should be a `canMeow` property (as a boolean) and no other properties.

An example React code would look like this:

```js
export default function SomeReactComponent({ type, ...other }: Cat | Dog) {
    switch (type) {
        case "dog":
            return <DogComponent {...other} />
        case "cat":
            return <CatComponent {...other} />
        default:
            throw new Error("Unknown animal type.")
    }
}

function DogComponent({ canBark }: { canBark: boolean }) {}

function CatComponent({ canMeow }: { canBark: boolean }) {}
```

However, I get this error on `DogComponent`:

```
Type '{ canBark: boolean; } | { canMeow: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { canBark: boolean; }'.
  Property 'canBark' is missing in type '{ canMeow: boolean; }' but required in type '{ canBark: boolean; }'.ts(2322)
```

and this error on `CatComponent`:

```
Type '{ canBark: boolean; } | { canMeow: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { canBark: boolean; }'.
  Property 'canBark' is missing in type '{ canMeow: boolean; }' but required in type '{ canBark: boolean; }'.ts(2322)
```

When I create a `Animal` interface with all possible values, it works:

```js
interface Animal {
    type: "dog" | "cat"
    canBark: boolean | undefined
    canMeow: boolean | undefined
}
interface Dog extends Animal {
    type: "dog"
    canBark: boolean
}

interface Cat extends Animal {
    type: "cat"
    canMeow: boolean
}
```

However, it's a bit tedious to write these base classes for every React component, is there a way to accomplish this without writing an `Animal` class?

Answer (score 2):

Typescript is not smart enough to follow the fact that `type` and `other` are actually entangled. There is an open issue about [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46680) one that might see improvement, as Typescript has just recently (in 4.6) added support for narrowing such entangled types with this [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46680)

One simple option is to not de-structure the props in the parameters, narrow them first, and then pass them directly to the component or de-structure the `type` prop out:

```
export default function SomeReactComponent(o: Cat | Dog) {
    switch (o.type) {
        case "dog":
            return <DogComponent {...o} />
        case "cat":
            return <CatComponent {...o} />
        default:
            throw new Error("Unknown animal type.")
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChgA7GJKTdJOAEQgHM4BvUubuGATzBIAXHABEAE1aiuPNCgoAhFFADWIgEYQIAG1QVSAX1LkqNOmgYBhFPE49eA4WLkxp9uRQCySCAHcNWrryhsZIAB6QsHDiSHQArtpYcRQYwBAUcADKuEjI6DCWuJAUSFQAFBAi1vAAPkysAJQcMtwAzr7AMGgAFnAVAHT8gk129rIorQwSUkItY-ZEMHFQGQA8zCyF4Omltv37EAZwAPQAfHPuE1MuorPz84vLa9Vbxbsc+-2HJ+f30bEoBIwO5-Hgwbo4XxwEpQgCiUBwUDKogAqhQVBQ-Bl5KAUNoHIJ+qIGnMjEZSJhkql0vVNkUduV2HAPEpVHADCImSzlGo4JodHp2SM4I8VtCEtoAITs4yUlIwNIZF70kqM5nybx+dmc9VeHz+PmBQUGYWijIUCXS9lAA)

You can also destructure after the narrowing:

```
export default function SomeReactComponent(o: Cat | Dog) {
    switch (o.type) {
        case "dog": {
            const { type, ...other } = o
            return <DogComponent {...other} />
        }
        case "cat": {
            const { type, ...other } = o
            return <CatComponent {...other} />
        }
        default:
            throw new Error("Unknown animal type.")
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChgA7GJKTdJOAEQgHM4BvUubuGATzBIAXHABEAE1aiuPNCgoAhFFADWIgEYQIAG1QVSAX1LkqNOmgYBhFPE49eA4WLkxp9uRQCySCAHcNWrryhsZIAB6QsHDiSHQArtpYcRQYwBAUcADKuEjI6DCWuJAUSFQAFBAi1vAAPkysAJQcMtwAzr7AMGgAFnAVAHT8gk129rIorQwSUiKjY2No6a22DoIANHD9WxAw3TRwBnAAvHAQLfM8RDBxUBkAPMwsheDppbZb-Tt7UIcA9AB853sRgucDkk2cNlEsyBF0WFGWHFWSA2Hy++0OJzOoPsVxu92qz2Kbw4aN2ND+gNBIIuMXiiSEsPmuxwvjgJTZAFEoDgoGVRABVCgqCh+DLyUAobTI-qiBrnIxGUiYZKpdL1J5FV7ldhg+RKVQHWZ6xTKNRwTQ6PQHEZwPG3dkJbQAQgOxhVKRgaQyhK1JR1Ju8fiNSI8Qf8FsC1oMtvtGQoTtdByAA)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to destructure the props since `type` should not be passed to `DogComponent` nor to `CatComponent`

Comment: If you are not explicitly forbidding it probably will not cause any issues in react. You can desreucture after the narrowing, added to the asnwer